# Cannot access a simple method preformed without game crashing

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a simple game to learn how to use animation with SKSpriteNodes in Swift. My game features a hero that runs along a surface positioned in the center of the screen. The hero can flip to the top or bottom to avoid randomly generated pipes. The flip() method for the hero crashes the application whenever it is run for some reason. I have rewritten it to the best of my ability, but it still crashes. Please let me know if anything hops out at you as incorrect. 
GameScene.swift

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  marioRunner
//
//  Created by nick on 11/18/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var movingGround: MLMovingGround!
    var hero: MLHero!
    var wallGenerator: MLWallGenerator!
    var isStarted = false

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 201.0/255.5, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        movingGround = MLMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 20))
        movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)
        addChild(movingGround)

        let hero = MLHero()
        hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.size.height/2)
        self.addChild(hero)

        wallGenerator = MLWallGenerator(color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: view.frame.size)
        wallGenerator.position = view.center
        addChild(wallGenerator)
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    }

    func start() {
        isStarted = true
        movingGround.start()
        wallGenerator.startGeneratingWallsEvery(1)
        hero.flip()
    }

    func gameOver() {
        hero.stop()
    }


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        //gameOver()
        hero.body.color = UIColor.orangeColor()
        print("HIT")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if isStarted == false{
            start()
        } else {
            hero.flip()
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

MLHero.swift

```
//
//  MLHero.swift
//  marioRunner
//
//  Created by nick on 12/7/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Supreme Leader. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class MLHero: SKSpriteNode {
    var body: SKSpriteNode!
    var arm: SKSpriteNode!
    var leftFoot: SKSpriteNode!
    var rightFoot: SKSpriteNode!
    var isUpsideDown = false
    init() {
        super.init(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(32, 44))
        loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size)
        body = SKSpriteNode(color:UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 40))
        body.position = CGPointMake(0, 2)
        addChild(body)
        let skinColor = UIColor(red:207.0/255.0, green:193.0/255.0, blue: 168.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let face = SKSpriteNode(color: skinColor, size: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 2))
        face.position = CGPointMake(0, 6)
        body.addChild(face)
        let eyeColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let leftEye = SKSpriteNode(color: eyeColor, size: CGSizeMake(6,6))
        let rightEye = leftEye.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        let pupil = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blackColor(), size: CGSizeMake(3,3))
        pupil.position = CGPointMake(2, 0)
        leftEye.addChild(pupil)
        rightEye.addChild(pupil.copy() as! SKSpriteNode)
        leftEye.position = CGPointMake(-4, 0)
        face.addChild(leftEye)
        rightEye.position = CGPointMake(14, 0)
        face.addChild(rightEye)
    }
    /*func performOneRunCycle() {
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 2, duration: 0.05)
        let down = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -2, duration: 0.05)
    }*/

    func loadPhysicsBodyWithSize(size: CGSize) {
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: size)
        physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = heroCategory
        physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = wallCategory
        physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    }

    func flip() {
        isUpsideDown = !isUpsideDown
        var scale: CGFloat
        if isUpsideDown {
            scale = -1.0
        } else {
           scale = 1.0
        }
        let translate = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: scale*(size.height + kMLGroundHeight), duration: 0.1)
        let flip = SKAction.scaleYTo(scale, duration: 0.1)

        runAction(translate)
        runAction(flip)
    }

    func stop() {
        //body.removeAllActions()
        print("stopped")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

This is the crash report I am receiving: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKKvZ.png 
It details that the hero object is nil. I am unsure how it can be nil if I have instantiated it properly. 
Please let me know if you need another/every file of the project in case these two files are not enough.
Thanks

Comment: You need to post exact details of the crash. What's the full error message? Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: @rmaddy added the crash report thanks

Comment: Don't post an image. Update your question with the error message and point out the line causing the crash.

Comment: in `didMoveToView` you are assigning your new Hero to a local variable, rather than the instance property.  You want `self.hero = MLHero()` rather than `let hero=`